# Not retrieving jars from maven nexus setup specific to project

Tags: maven, download, dependencies, settings, nexus

Got 2 Nexus maven repo - one serving or holding common jars - mostly from maven central & some others. And other - project specific maven nexus, where it holds 2 thirdparty jars which are needed for compilation of current project of interest.

Below is updates which is added to refer to local nexus maven setup & corresponding dependencies..

`pom.xml` snippet :

```
<project 
...


<!-- download plugins from this *proj specific* repo -->
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>zzz-maven</id>
  <name>zzz-maven</name>
  <url>http://blah.blah.com/nexus/content/repositories/zzz-maven</url>
  <releases>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
 </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>zzz.zzz-report<groupId>
        <artifactId>zzz-report<artifactId>
        <version>1.2<version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <!-- And other dependency to fetch jars from common nexus (which is working fine) -->
```

Added below to `settings.xml` (highlighted in bold text) - one covering Url to retrieve proj specific jars & other part of authenticating to proj specific Nexus

```
<settings>   
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Common nexus across org - Anonymous access </name>
      <url>http://common-nexusxyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/maven</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>


  <profiles>
     </profile>
     <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

    <!--**Added this one** -->       
    </profile>
     <profile>
      <id>zzz-maven</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>zzz-maven</id>
          <name>zzz-maven</name>
          <url>http://blah.blah.com/nexus/content/repositories/zzz-maven</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>zzz-maven</activeProfile>  <!--**activated** additional one here -->
  </activeProfiles>

<servers>
  <server>   
   <id>zzz-maven</id>
   <username>userNameForZZZ</username> <!--**Specified** explicit password needed for proj specific maven nexus here -->
   <password>passwordForZZZ</password>
  </server>
</servers>

</settings>
```

But still throws out Warning & then the error for `mvn install` or `mvn compile` like :

```
[WARNING] The POM for zzz.zzz-report:zzz-report:jar:1.2 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Would like to know what is missing - so that it will download proj specific jars from proj specific maven nexus?

Tried with both `<repositories>` & `<pluginRepositories>` option in pom to consider for download

Expect it to connect to proj specific maven nexus & download dependency jar defined in pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined

```
<mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <name>Common nexus across org - Anonymous access </name>
  <url>http://common-nexusxyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/maven</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

which means that all requests (due to `mirrorOf` having the value `*`) are redirected to that particular repository, no matter what other repositories are defined in the POM or the `settings.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for response. Have tried with `<mirrorOf>central,zzz-maven</mirrorOf>` - but still seeing similar issue of non-download of proj specific jars located in proj specific maven nexus

Comment: I thought you _want_ to use `zzz-maven`? With your configuration, you are replacing all calls to `zzz-maven` by the mirror you defined.

Comment: Yes I want to use `zzz-maven` Nexus to consider downloading of jars (2 of them) which are non existed on common nexus. Hence to scan `zzz-maven` have added it as comma separated value instead of `*` per your answer..

Comment: Try `<mirrorOf>*,!central,!zzz-maven</mirrorOf>`.

Comment: Many Thanks!, it worked like charm. Accepted the answer. If possible kindly edit in your answer for other's ref..